# Android app deployment on over 100 devices

Tags: android, deployment

We have a fleet tracking Android app which is isntalled on around 100 mobiles.

Problem is to update each mobile whenever there is a patch release. And unfotunately we have not set auto-update.

Now we need to call each driver and follow the process of update from google play.

This is becoming very tedious as they have to go to google play, search the application and install/update it. 
And the mobiles are located all over the country.

Before it was easy as Goolge play was giving an option to know the apps installed on each mobile.

Need your advice on how do we manage/automate this update issue.

Comment: Do you have "push notification"?

Comment: Can't you just have auto-update? Or, via Google Play on the web, you can update them manually by being signed into the account with the phone.

Answer (score 0):

You could check a text file located on a server or something like that and then lookup if the current instaleld version is the same as the server version. If not you could download the new apk and open it. As far as I know this is not allowed by Google Play so you must remove the app from google play

Comment: In a similar vein of thinking, you could check the text file on the server when the app is launched and send the user a notification that they need to update the app. The notification can take them directly to the play store to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Build an in-app push notification that there's a new version and have an easy link to Google Play from it. However, this does have a bootstrapping problem, and you will have to make everyone install the new version manually (as in you call them and ask them to do it) at least once. Still, this is your only viable option, as Google Play developer agreement prohibits pushing app updates through other channels.

If you have email or IM contact with the drivers, you can also send them a message there's a new version with the direct link to the Google Play. They will have to open it on their device, of course.

The link format should be `market://details?id=com.mycompany.myapp`, `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mycompany.myapp`, or `http://market.android.com/details?id=id=com.mycompany.myapp`. Either of these three in general should work, though some OEMs have messed up their devices configuration and prevent Google Play app from intercepting the `http/https` form properly.